# Why `a: 2` is not raising a syntax exception in Python

Tags: python

Why is the Python interpreter not raising exception on the expression?

```bash
$ python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a : 2
>>>
```

I'd expect a syntax error.

Comment: The syntax is not wrong, its just there is nothing you have done to the a. But syntax is correct.

Comment: think its like a type hinting

Comment: given that it is not a syntax error, what could be the custom usage of such keyword?

Comment: a: int or a: SomeType is used to indicate the type hint for the variable a. Syntactically its not wrong. Eg usage:  a: int = 2

Comment: It is valid syntax as per the grammar of Python (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annotated-assignment-statements)). An expression is allowed after `:` and `2` is an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python interprets

```py
a : 2
```

as a *variable annotation* (see [PEP 526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/)).
Annotations can be used by code analysis tools such as type checkers.

You can access annotations of all variables via module attribute `__annotations__`

For instance in the code interpreter you'd get

```
>>> a : 2
>>> __annotations__
{'a': 2}
```